# Devise + Omniauth No Initializer file

Tags: oauth, devise, oauth-2.0, omniauth

I am adding facebook authentication to my web app.  Problem is that after I bundle installed the gems, it did not create this file.

```
 config/initializers/omniauth.rb
```

Has anyone had this problem?

Gems:

```
 #user authentication
 gem 'devise'
 gem 'opro'
 gem 'omniauth'
 gem 'omniauth-facebook'
 gem 'oauth2'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't be a problem.  It doesn't create it automatically and you don't need to create it manually either as you seem to be using it in conjunction with devise.  Instead, you can use the `config.omniauth` setting in your `devise.rb` initialiser.  Have you read the relevant devise wiki page? https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview

Also, note that you don't really need to specify omniauth and oauth2 in your Gemfile as they are dependencies of omniauth-facebook, so bundler should pull them in automatically.

Comment: I was writing exactly the same thing ehe Have an upvote.